# c++ get methods not returning pointer to a node

Tags: c++, list, file, pointers, text

I've narrowed down the issue with my program to the get methods of my North - West Node.

The overall purpose of the program to create a maze game from an input file and assign North East South and West. I believe all other functionality of the program is correct I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong in the four get methods.

The set methods do work as expected and I've included them as well as the constructor to show how the nodes are being initialized.

Additionally, I have verified that the file is being parsed correctly.

```
Node::Node(char e){

Name = e;
North = NULL;
East = NULL;
South = NULL;
West = NULL;

}


Node Node::get_North(){

    return *North;

}

Node Node::get_East(){

    return *East;

}

Node Node::get_South(){

    return *South;

}

Node Node::get_West(){

    return *West;

}

void Node::set_North(Node *n){
    //cout << "inside set_North\n";
    North = n;

}

void Node::set_East(Node *e){
    //cout << "inside set_East\n";
    East = e;

}

void Node::set_South(Node *s){
    //cout << "inside set_South\n";
    South = s;

}

void Node::set_West(Node *w){
    //cout << "inside set_West\n";
    West = w;

}
```

Any help in spotting the error will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to return `Node`s instead of `Node *`s? Do you realize that this will **copy** the nodes?

Comment: Your code is wrong.  Two possible solutions: 1) Change the signatures from "Node" to `*Node` (return a pointer, as you intended), or 2) Use references "&".   Here is a good tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: Aside: if you have a setFoo and a getFoo functions, your design is automatically suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Your getters are returning pointers although you mentioned their return type as plain objects.

So, instead of this:-

```
Node Node::get_North()
```

use

```
Node* Node::get_North()
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, it seems now that I have deeper problems than just the getter methods. I will continue to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

`return *NodeName` means that you return the actual `Node` instance instead of a pointer to one. It means that the data will be copied to your destination instead of the address of the data.

Simply change `*NodeName` to `NodeName`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you're most likely having is that you have a global list of nodes (your rooms [] array?), but you're returning copies of these objects which you then call the set method on... so you're not modifying the object required.

Think carefully about where the objects are stored, and  how they're passed around your program.